# Can I use http/https proxies or only socks5 for scraping wss/socket.io endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, web-scraping

Can I use http/https scraping proxies to scrape socket.io/wss endpoints from a website?

I want to hide real ip and prevent being blocked by the website.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io.connect('https://weather.example.com', {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    transports: ['wss'],
    agent: //some http agent/socks5 proxy agent?
});

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected');

    socket.emit('giveMeData');

    socket.on('someData', (data) => {
        console.log('data:', data);
    });
});
```

or is wss protocol suitable only to scrape via socks5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSockets will work over HTTP proxies and SOCKS proxies. Note that some HTTP proxies will block HTTPS or intercept it, which will also block both plain WS and WSS.